# Why won't an anchor adjacent sibling work with an other element tags?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm stumped at why placing anything next to an anchor tag won't work like any other element tag using the CSS adjacent sibling `+`.

For example when I try doing this, I have no success.

```css
h2 + a {
  background-color: red; /* or anything next to <a> per se */
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<h2>H2 Example</h2>
<a href="#">anchor tag</a>
```

This seems to be specific to the anchor tag. I have not found anything on this, if anyone knows, please shed some light on this matter.

Comment: it's working fine, I have created a snippet for you

Comment: @TemaniAfif Pretty stumped! I have removed all my styling and have tried it in a different environment with no luck

Comment: @TemaniAfif try a `margin-top` for example

Comment: margin-top doesn't work on inline element, this is a different issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197639/discussion-between-diego-and-temani-afif).

Comment: Ah, i see, I'm telling you I knew I was missing something, didn't come to mind that anchor tags displayed inline by default =(

Comment: just add `inline-block` as a `display` for the `a` tag if you want the `margin-top` rule to be applied.